# Can those who eat insects be considered vegetarians?

Tags: lacto-ovo-vegetarianism, is-it-vegetarian, entomophagy

If one eats insects as part of their diet, can it be considered vegetarian?

Comment: What if I don't *realize* I'm eating insects, because the eggs and larvae are extremely small and hidden in the fruit I eat?

Comment: The answer is obviously **no**, since insects are animals. Are you actually asking whether it is *ethical* to eat them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on whether you consider insects animals or not.

If you are a vegan/vegetarian and you don't want to eat anything in the biological kingdom *Animalia*, you can't eat insects.

> Kingdom:  Animalia
>   Phylum: Arthropoda
>   (unranked): Ectognatha
>   Class:  Insecta

([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect))

Many people have the attitude "if something has to die for me to eat it, I don't want to eat it", so they say no to insects also.

However, since [insects don't feel pain the same way other animals do](https://www.quora.com/Do-insects-feel-pain/answer/Marc-Srour?srid=bj1i), some people are perfectly fine with eating them.

It's really comes down to what you consider an animal to be, and whether your stance is not to eat animals or not to eat things that don't like being eaten. (i.e. plants don't know and therefore don't care about being eaten)

Comment: *if something has to die for me to eat it, I don't want to eat it* implies fruitarianism.

Comment: @gerrit which is a subset of vegan/vegetarianism IMO.

Comment: Probably, but only a very small subset of vegans are fruitarian, in my experience.

Comment: I think it's misleading to say "whether you consider insects animals or not" because they *are* unambiguously animals. There's no room for opinion there, at least.

Comment: Is taxonomic membership necessarily relevant here? I think most ethical vegans/vegetarians care more about sentience (it just so happens that that correlates with being in Animalia 99% of the time).

Comment: @JoeRocc not sure, but I added it anyway. Plus, cows are sentient. Only humans are.

Comment: If you mean to say that only humans are sentient, that's incorrect. Most animals are capable of conscious states just like humans. The Cambridge Declaration on Consciousness spelled this out fairly explicitely. [This article summarises it fairly well](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/animal-emotions/201306/universal-declaration-animal-sentience-no-pretending). Also see the [wikipedia page on animal consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_consciousness).

Comment: @JoeRocc oh I read sapient, sorry.

Comment: A purely semantic, or let's say literal approach towards vegetarianism isn't helpful. Someone who kills an ant is literally a killer, but we wouldn't refer to this person as a killer.

Comment: At no point did the author in the Quora article state or even suggest that "insects don't feel pain the same way other animals do". Also, as C_Z_ mentioned, "[Insects] _are_ unambiguously animals." Riker, can you please adjust your answer accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

The only honest answers are "it's up to you" and "for what purpose?" In short, you can call yourself whatever you want.

- If you're designing a survey to track lifestyle by diet, you might consider lumping in insect-eaters with vegetarians if you feel they have more in common there than they do with meat eaters.
- Call yourself a vegan if you want to draw attention to ethical choices you have made regarding your food that are restrictive against meat. Or if it's just easier to explain than, "insects are delicious." Do not worry about the vegan police :)