# Are cereals or any other crop grown by humans vegan?

Tags: is-it-vegan

The process of growing a crop involves ploughing the land and using pesticides. While ploughing we kill many insects and worms in the soil and by using pesticides we intentionally kill the insects.

Are these crops grown by humans really vegan ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the use of pesticides considered vegan?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/360/is-the-use-of-pesticides-considered-vegan)

Comment: Not really the question is, are the crops grown by humans vegan ?. As it involves killing of animals is it really ethical? even if we not consume animals

Comment: Humans can crow crops without ploughing or pesticides.  You might still kill a worm by stepping on it, nothing is vegan if you take it far enough, much to my disappointment.

Comment: Take another look at the answer to the suggested duplicate question -- it includes a discussion of both ploughing and pesticides, even though the question itself only asked about pesticides.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of vegan is not consuming or using animal products. If you start looking at animals harmed in the process of making other things then you run into a problem because all life is interconnected. It is extremely difficult to avoid harming life at some point in the production of food. But by choosing to not consume or use animal products, vegans limit the amount of harm done. So, yes, eating plants is still called vegan.